# Automatic Hibernate index creation too long

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am back with a bug/problem that came to sunlight now. Usually I test the local development and changes on an H2DB but as I know, this has to work on Oracle and MSSQL too. 
Now testing on oracle again this problem occurred:
The Key COR_VIEWSETTINGSCOR_USERSETTINGS_FK0 and COR_VIEWSETTINGSCOR_USERSETTINGS_FK1 are generated automatic and are way too long for an oracle db.
To know how these keys are created I will now show you the entities UserSettings and UserViewSettings.
hint: you can overlook the entities and go further to the edits if they confuse you. maybe you can still help me.

**UserSettings**

```
/**

      The Class UserSettings.

*/
@org.hibernate.envers.Audited
@DataObject( value =  UserSettings.DATA_OBJECT_NAME )
@CRUDDefinition( supportsRead = true, supportsCreate = true, supportsUpdate = true, supportsDelete = true )
@Entity( name = UserSettings.DATA_OBJECT_NAME )
@NamedQuery( name = UserSettings.DATA_OBJECT_NAME, query = "from userSettings e where e.name = :name" )
@javax.persistence.Inheritance( strategy = javax.persistence.InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS )
@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride( name = "id", column = @Column( name = "USERSETTINGS_ID" ) )
} )
@Table( name = "COR_USERSETTINGS", indexes = {
  @javax.persistence.Index( name="COR_USERSETTINGS_FK0", columnList = "SETTINGSTYPE_ID" ),
  @javax.persistence.Index( name="COR_USERSETTINGS_FK1", columnList = "USER_ID" ),
}
)
public class UserSettings extends NamedRevisionEntity implements NameSettingsType, NameSettings
{
  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /** The Constant DATA_OBJECT_NAME. */
  public static final String DATA_OBJECT_NAME = "userSettings";

  @javax.persistence.Basic( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = false )
  @Column( name = "SETTINGS", nullable = false, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
  @javax.persistence.Lob
  private java.lang.String settings;

  @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = false )
  @javax.persistence.JoinColumn( name = "SETTINGSTYPE_ID", nullable = false, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
  private SettingsType settingsType;

  @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = true )
  @javax.persistence.JoinColumn( name = "USER_ID", nullable = true, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
  private User user;



  public SettingsType getSettingsType()
  {
    return settingsType;
  }

  public void setSettingsType( SettingsType settingsType )
  {
    this.settingsType = settingsType;
  }

  public User getUser()
  {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser( User user )
  {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public java.lang.String getSettings()
  {
    return settings;
  }

  public void setSettings( java.lang.String settings )
  {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDataObjectName()
  {
    return DATA_OBJECT_NAME;
  }



  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( super.toString() );

    builder.append( ", " );
    try
    {
        builder.append( ToStringUtils.referenceToString( "settingsType", "SettingsType", this.settingsType ) );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
      builder.append( ex.getClass().getName()  );
      builder.append( ": " );
      builder.append( ex.getMessage() );
    }
    builder.append( ", " );
    try
    {
        builder.append( ToStringUtils.referenceToString( "user", "User", this.user ) );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
      builder.append( ex.getClass().getName()  );
      builder.append( ": " );
      builder.append( ex.getMessage() );
    }

    builder.append( "]" );
    return builder.toString();
  }

}
```

**UserViewSettings**

```
/**

      The Class UserViewSettings.

*/
@org.hibernate.envers.Audited
@DataObject( value =  UserViewSettings.DATA_OBJECT_NAME )
@CRUDDefinition( supportsRead = true, supportsCreate = true, supportsUpdate = true, supportsDelete = true )
@Entity( name = UserViewSettings.DATA_OBJECT_NAME )
@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride( name = "id", column = @Column( name = "VIEWSETTINGS_ID" ) )
} )
@Table( name = "COR_VIEWSETTINGS", uniqueConstraints = {
  @javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint( name="COR_VIEWSETTINGS_UNQ1", columnNames = { "NAME", "SETTINGSTYPE_ID", "VIEW_NAME", "VIEWTYPE_ID" } ),
}
, indexes = {
  @javax.persistence.Index( name="COR_VIEWSETTINGS_FK0", columnList = "VIEWTYPE_ID" ),
}
)
public class UserViewSettings extends UserSettings implements NameViewName, NameViewType
{
  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /** The Constant DATA_OBJECT_NAME. */
  public static final String DATA_OBJECT_NAME = "userViewSettings";

  @javax.persistence.Basic( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = false )
  @Column( name = "VIEW_NAME", nullable = false, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
  private java.lang.String viewName;

  @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = true )
  @javax.persistence.JoinColumn( name = "VIEWTYPE_ID", nullable = true, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
  private ViewType viewType;



  public java.lang.String getViewName()
  {
    return viewName;
  }

  public void setViewName( java.lang.String viewName )
  {
    this.viewName = viewName;
  }

  public ViewType getViewType()
  {
    return viewType;
  }

  public void setViewType( ViewType viewType )
  {
    this.viewType = viewType;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDataObjectName()
  {
    return DATA_OBJECT_NAME;
  }



  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( super.toString() );

    builder.append( ", " );
    builder.append( "viewName" );
    builder.append( "=" );
    builder.append( this.viewName );
    builder.append( ", " );
    try
    {
        builder.append( ToStringUtils.referenceToString( "viewType", "ViewType", this.viewType ) );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
      builder.append( ex.getClass().getName()  );
      builder.append( ": " );
      builder.append( ex.getMessage() );
    }

    builder.append( "]" );
    return builder.toString();
  }

}
```

Starting Wildfly 10.0.0 with Hibernate 5.2 and an Oracle 11 Database then results in the error that the automatic generated Keys **COR_VIEWSETTINGSCOR_USERSETTINGS_FK0** and **COR_VIEWSETTINGSCOR_USERSETTINGS_FK1** are naturally too long for the database.

I took a look at the NamingStrategies for Hibernate and even tried some but they didn't change the error for me.

How can I impact the generation of these keys?

EDIT:

So turning on DEBUG gave me this:

```
2016-11-29 09:22:03,190 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) create index COR_USERSETTINGS_FK0 on COR_USERSETTINGS (SETTINGSTYPE_ID)
2016-11-29 09:22:03,190 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) create index COR_USERSETTINGS_FK1 on COR_USERSETTINGS (USER_ID)
2016-11-29 09:22:03,190 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) create index COR_VIEWSETTINGSCOR_USERSETTINGS_FK0 on COR_VIEWSETT INGS(SETTINGSTYPE_ID)
2016-11-29 09:22:03,190 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) create index COR_VIEWSETTINGSCOR_USERSETTINGS_FK1 on COR_VIEWSETTINGS (USER_ID)
2016-11-29 09:22:03,190 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) create index COR_VIEWSETTINGS_FK0 on COR_VIEWSETTINGS (VIEWTYPE_ID)
```

Now I found the Class **ImplicitIndexNameSource** in the package **org.hibernate.boot.model.naming** but the internet doesn't really give examples what I can do with this and it seems to be an empty class for a long since a long time.

EDIT 2:

The previous edit seems to be a wrong path. I found the place where these logs are created. It's **StandardIndexExporter** which gets called from **SchemaCreatorImpl**. So I need to dig even deeper into the framework but if somebody sees this. Is this the right path? Can I modify code so that He will do the thing I want? It seems to be the **hbm2ddl** that is the culprit since the index get's created in StandardIndexExport in these lines:

```
final String indexNameForCreation;
if ( dialect.qualifyIndexName() ) {
    indexNameForCreation = jdbcEnvironment.getQualifiedObjectNameFormatter().format(
            new QualifiedNameImpl(
                    index.getTable().getQualifiedTableName().getCatalogName(),
                    index.getTable().getQualifiedTableName().getSchemaName(),
                    jdbcEnvironment.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier( index.getName() )
            ),
            jdbcEnvironment.getDialect()
    );
}
else {
    indexNameForCreation = index.getName();
}
final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder()
        .append( "create index " )
        .append( indexNameForCreation )
        .append( " on " )
        .append( tableName )
        .append( " (" );

boolean first = true;
Iterator<Column> columnItr = index.getColumnIterator();
while ( columnItr.hasNext() ) {
    final Column column = columnItr.next();
    if ( first ) {
        first = false;
    }
    else {
        buf.append( ", " );
    }
    buf.append( ( column.getQuotedName( dialect ) ) );
}
buf.append( ")" );
return new String[] { buf.toString() };
```

I would appreciate help a lot. This is getting really frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working.
Answering for future people that might find this and have the same issue.

The index key gets created by the dialect of oracle that hibernate is referrencing to. So what had to be done was implementing an custom OracleDialect that overrides the method **getIndexExporter** and points to the custom IndexExporter. In this IndexExporter you can then modify the way the keys are created. In my case I fixed the solution like this:

```
  /**
   * Gets the correct index name if it is a index for a TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance and longer than
   * 30 chars.
   *
   * @param index the index to decide for
   * @return the correct index name
   */
  private String getCorrectIndexName( Index index )
  {
    if ( index.getTable() instanceof DenormalizedTable && index.getName().length() > 30 )
    {
      String prefixedTable = index.getTable().getName();
      String tableName = prefixedTable.substring( prefixedTable.indexOf( '_' ) + 1, prefixedTable.length() );
      tableName = shortenName( tableName );
      Iterator<Column> columnItr = index.getColumnIterator();
      String reference;

      if ( columnItr.hasNext() )
      {
        reference = extractReference( columnItr.next() );
      }
      else
      {
        /** backup strategy to prevent exceptions */
        reference = shortenName( NamingHelper.INSTANCE.hashedName( index.getName() ) );
      }

      return tableName + "_" + reference;
    }
    return index.getName();
  }

  /**
   * Extract the reference column of the index and hash the full name before shortening it with
   * shortenName().
   *
   * @param index the index to extract the reference from.
   * @return the reference with an appended _FK(hashedReference).
   */
  private String extractReference( Column column )
  {
    String reference = column.getQuotedName( dialect );
    String md5Hash = NamingHelper.INSTANCE.hashedName( reference );
    md5Hash = md5Hash.substring( md5Hash.length() - 4, md5Hash.length() );
    reference = shortenName( reference );

    return reference + "_FK" + md5Hash;
  }

  /**
   * Shorten the name to a maximum of 11 chars if it's longer.
   *
   * @param reference the reference to shorten
   * @return the shortened string
   */
  private static String shortenName( String reference )
  {
    if ( reference.length() > 11 )
    {
      return reference.substring( 0, 11 );
    }
    return reference;
  }
```

this had to be called in the Overriden function **getSqlCreateStrings**. the changed lines look like this:

```
  String indexName = getCorrectIndexName( index );
  indexNameForCreation = jdbcEnvironment.getQualifiedObjectNameFormatter()
      .format(
          new QualifiedNameImpl( index.getTable().getQualifiedTableName().getCatalogName(),
              index.getTable().getQualifiedTableName().getSchemaName(), jdbcEnvironment.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier( indexName ) ),
          jdbcEnvironment.getDialect() );
```

I hope that helps someone.